# Simple Form For that adapts based on checkbox input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, simple-form-for

I am working on a personal project where I want users to be able to create profiles (*I am using Devise to handle users)*. These can either be public or private, whereby public profiles require more input fields than private profiles. Is there any way I can cause these additional form fields to only appear if the user chooses his profile to be public?

I tried looking on StackOverflow and previous threads on here but couldn't find anything. I saw a few suggestions for the Cocoon gem but couldn't get that to work.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@User, url: registration_path(@User)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :first_name, required: true, autofocus: true %>
    <%= f.input :email,
                required: true,
                input_html: { autocomplete: "email" }%>
    <%= f.input :public, required: false, label: "Enable public profile?" %>
    
    ## Ideally the following two-fields would only show if public is clicked
    ## Best case they would be required fields if this happens and not required if                     
   it does not

    <%= f.input :linkedin_link, required: false, label: "Linked-In Profile Link" %>
    <%= f.input :photo, as: :file, label: "Profile Picture", accept: "image/*", hint: "Why not use your Linked-In profile picture? (png and jpg only)" %>
    
    <%= f.input :password, required: true, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length), input_html: { autocomplete: "new-password" } %> 
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true, input_html: { autocomplete: "new-password" } %> 
    <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up", class: "btn-success btn-full-width" %> 
    </div> 
<% end %>
```

Looking forward to learning something new :) Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: If you want the DOM to significantly change, you'll need to introduce some JavaScript. You could put the fields you want to hide in a hidden div and show it when public is selected. Stimulus.JS has a great and easy to use JS library for RoR.

Comment: Perfect, I will check that out. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: On a side note `@User` is a bug waiting to happen. Name variables in snake_case (all lower case) as per the language conventions. In Ruby everything is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve it with this.

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('div[name="showthis"]').hide();

    //show it when the checkbox is clicked
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $('div[name="showthis"]').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('div[name="showthis"]').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-inputs">
  <%= f.input :first_name, required: true, autofocus: true %>
  <%= f.input :email, required: true, input_html: { autocomplete: "email" }%>
  <%= f.input :public, required: false, label: "Enable public profile?" %>

  <div name="showthis">
    <%= f.input :linkedin_link, required: false, label: "Linked-In Profile Link" %>
    <%= f.input :photo, as: :file, label: "Profile Picture", accept: "image/*", hint: "Why not use your Linked-In profile picture? (png and jpg only)" %>
  </div>

  <%= f.input :password, required: true, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length), input_html: { autocomplete: "new-password" } %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true, input_html: { autocomplete: "new-password" } %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up", class: "btn-success btn-full-width" %>
</div>
```